# Python regex fails when ? involved in repeating group

Tags: python, regex

Trying to match any number of comma separated 7 character strings that can include digits, _ and ?.

```
x = re.compile(r"^([0-9_\?]{7})(,\1)*$")

>>> x.match("123456?")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0046C800>
>>> x.match("12345??")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x023483C8>
>>> x.match("1234???")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0046C800>
>>> x.match("123????")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x023483C8>
>>> x.match("12?????")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0046C800>
>>> x.match("1??????")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x023483C8>
>>> x.match("???????")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0046C800>
>>> x.match("???????,1234567")
>>>
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^This is where it fails

vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvBut repetition works if I don't have a ? in the string

```
>>> x.match("1234567,1234567")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x023483C8>
```

I've also tried it with:

```
x = re.compile(r"^([0-9_\\?]{7})(,\1)*$")
```

But that just allows it to match the \ character (as expected).

What is wrong with my regex?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would expect that last one to succeed since `???????` and `1234567` are not the same

Comment: Do you want to *recognize* a string with these numbers, or use the `Match` object to extract these numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\1` is a backreference that will match what the referenced group *matched*, not what it can match. If you want to allow that pattern to appear twice, just write it twice:

```
r"^([0-9_?]{7})(,[0-9_?]{7})*$"
```

(Also note that `?` doesn’t need escaping inside a character set.)

Answer (score 3):

Why do you expect `'???????,1234567'` to match? Clearly the second part (`1234567`) doesn't match the `\1` backref (`???????`).

You'll have the same problem without any `?` characters:

```
>>> x = re.compile(r"^([0-9_\?]{7})(,\1)*$")
>>> x.match('1234567,1234568')
```

This returns `None`. But:

```
>>> x.match('???????,???????')
<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x104208140>
```

So, the whole `?` issue is completely irrelevant. (You actually shouldn't be escaping the question mark; you don't want to do that inside a character class. But that isn't your problem.)

If you want to match 1 or more comma-separated copies of the same thing, you need to match a copy without a comma, plus 0 or more with a preceding comma, like this:

```
>>> x = re.compile(r"^([0-9_?]{7})(,([0-9_?]{7}))*$")
```

If you want to match 0 or more… well, depending on how you define that, it's either a match-everything tautology, or the previous wrapped in a big `?`.